# UIPanGestureRecognizer get swipe distance in pixels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to track the horizontal distance that a user has swiped using a UIPanGestureRecognizer, but I'm having difficulty interpreting the results. Here is the code that I am using:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint startLocation;

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        startLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint stopLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
        CGFloat dx = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x;
        NSLog(@"dx: %f", dx);
    }
}
```

If I swipe left-to-right, I get output something like this:

`dx: 50328911327402404790403072.000000`

My screen is only 320 pixels wide, so my end result cannot be greater than 320. Is there a problem with my code or am I just interpreting this number incorrectly? How can I get this value stated in pixels? Thanks!

Comment: As @Aaron Brager sais, change CGPoint startLocation; for: static CGPoint startLocation; is the faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`startLocation` doesn't persist after `handlePan:` returns, so you're getting garbage.

Either declare `startLocation` as `static` or save it in an instance variable / property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPanGestureRecognizer as below:-

```
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
    firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY);

[[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGFloat velocityX = (0.2*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);


    CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + velocityX;
    CGFloat finalY = firstY;
```